# LINQ association - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have three tables and I have used edmx designer to add associations between them. Below is how they are linked.

(table1) Loans - (table 2) Investor : Many to One relationship 
(Table2) Investor - (Table3) InvestorInfo : One to Many relationship

I want to get [1] Total loans count sold to one investor, [2] Investor name and  [3] investor's service fee which is stored in Table3 at idx = 2005 for each investor ("investor id & idx" is primary key of table3 - InvestorInfo table).

How do I do that in below query? I am forced to select 'FirstOrDefault()' to access any column in Table3 (See commented lines). If I use FirstOrDefualt, I get a record where idx = 1 and not 2005.

```
 var loanPurchaseData = (from cd in entity.Table1
                        //where cd.Table2.Table3.Select(x => x.IDX == 2005)
                        //where cd.ULDD_SET_POOLS.ULDD_SET_POOLDT.FirstOrDefault().SORT_ID == 2005
                        group cd by new { cd.Table4.PurchaseDate, cd.Number } into grp
                        select new
                        {
                            investor = grp.FirstOrDefault().Investor,
                            no_of_loans = grp.Count(),                                               
                            sort_id = grp.FirstOrDefault().Table2.Table3.FirstOrDefault().SORT_ID,
                            service_fee_rate = grp.FirstOrDefault().Table2.Table3.FirstOrDefault().DT_REAL_PERC_VALUE
                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear - I don't understand whether idx is in Table3 or Table1, and what you want to select, but I will assume you have a many-one-many schema, where an `Investor` has zero or more `Loans` & zero or more `InvestorInfos`. You want to get, say, all of the loans which join to investor info with `idx = 2005`. Correct me if I'm wrong, and correct your question if I'm right!

Starting with your `InvestorInfo` object, you know that there's only one `Investor` but there will be zero or more `Loans`.

```
// only one InvestorInfo for idx, but this isn't clear in your question
var investorInfo = context.InvestorInfos.SingleOrDefault(i => i.idx == 2005);

var loans = investorInfo.Investor.Loans;
```

The crux of your problem is that you cannot get 'the loan service fee' for an investor info. Why not? Because that investor has 5 loans. Which one do you want?

```
-- we can get the maximum, minimum, sum, etc...
var max = loans.Max(l => l.DT_REAL_PERC_VALUE);
var min = loans.Min(l => l.DT_REAL_PERC_VALUE);
var min = loans.Sum(l => l.DT_REAL_PERC_VALUE);
```

Again it's not clear what you are trying to do, nor what your data actually looks like, but in a one-many relationship you will necessarily have more than one of the 'many' side for each of the 'one' side.

---

To get the max, use the `Max` operator.

```
service_fee = grp.Max(l => l.Table2.Table3.Max(t => t.DT_REAL_PERC_VALUE))
```

Comment: No. 'DT_REAL_PERC_VALUE' column is not available under loans object. I have to refer it like this  l => l.Table2.Table3.FirstOrDefault().DT_REAL_PERC_VALUE

Comment: Did you read my answer? You can't get `DT_REAL_PERC_VALUE` for a user because it's a one-many relationship, and they might have multiple loans. If I had two loans, how do you expect to get `DT_REAL_PERC_VALUE` for me? You will need to get the average, or the max, or the min, etc...

Comment: I am trying to get MAX only.


service_fee = grp.Max(l => l.Table2.Table3.FirstOrDefault().DT_REAL_PERC_VALUE)